# update a sharepoint list coulmn value from a remote computer programmatically

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, sharepoint

I have a asp website which reads a sharepoint list using SSIS and displays it on a grid-view. Then, on the click of a button, a table in a SQL database gets updated with some of the list values. What I want is,for the button click to also update a column on the sharepoint list, so that the row is ignored by the SSIS package when run again. And the website and the sharepoint are on different servers . Which is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Because its on a different server, I would recommend using the SharePoint Web Services and AJAX. Here is an AJAX example of updating a task item:

```
function updateTaskPercent(taskId, pctComplete, taskStatus) {
    var targetUrl = "../_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
    var listName = "Project Tasks";
    var updateItemXml;
    updateItemXml =
        "<Batch OnError=\"Continue\" ListVersion=\"1\" ViewName=\"\">" +
        "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Update\">" +
        "<Field Name=\"ID\">" + taskId + "</Field>" +
        "<Field Name=\"Status\">" + taskStatus + "</Field>" +
        "<Field Name=\"_x0025__x0020_Complete\">" + pctComplete + "</Field>" +
        "</Method>" +
        "</Batch>";
    var soapEnv = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        " <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "   <soap:Body>     <UpdateListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">" +
        "       <listName>" + listName + "</listName>" +
        "       <updates>" + updateItemXml + "</updates>" +
        "     </UpdateListItems>  </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: targetUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");
        },
        complete: function(msg) {
            if ($(msg.responseXML).find("ErrorText").text().length === 0) { // success
                SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
                addNotification("Task Updated");
            } else {
                //Failure
                var errorString = $(msg.responseXML).find("ErrorText").text();
                if (errorString.length === 0) {
                    errorString = $(msg.responseXML).find("FaultString").text();
                }
                errorString = errorString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing this function go on the aspx file as a script tag and I should call this function from code behind with the arguments ?

Comment: Yes, I would imagine that a function similar to the example I provided will be called in your button click event.